# Django Error: could not convert string to float in source code not in my own code

Tags: python, django

When I try run `python manage.py migrate` to synchronize database I get error

```
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 346, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 394, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 445, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 222, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 110, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 148, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 115, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 62, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 179, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 77, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(field)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 211, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 710, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 702, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1804, in get_prep_value
    return float(value)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: Jestem watowcem
```

models.py file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.

class ProductWithFrames(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ProductWithFrames, self).get_queryset().filter(has_frame=True)

class ProductWithoutFrames(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ProductWithoutFrames, self).get_queryset().filter(has_frame=False)

class Product(models.Model):
    PRODUCT_SIZE = (
        ('50x50', '50x50'),
        ('50x70', '50x70'),
        ('70x50', '70x50'),
    )
    product_id = models.IntegerField()
    product_size = models.CharField(max_length = 5, choices = PRODUCT_SIZE, default='50x50')
    product_price = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    has_frame = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    products = models.Manager()
    products_with_frames = ProductWithFrames()
    products_without_frames = ProductWithoutFrames()

    def _has_frame(self):
        if self.has_frame == True:
            return True
        return False
    # _has_frame.boolean = True
    # has_frame = property(_has_frame)


    def __str__(self):
        if self.has_frame:
            return "Oprawiony rozmiar ramy {} kosztuje {} zl".format(self.product_size, self.product_price)
        else:
            return "Nieoprawiony rozmiar ramy {} kosztuje {} zl".format(self.product_size, self.product_price)
```

So in my own code I haven't got any String like "Jestem watowcem". I have just removed it for test but error is still visible.
`python manage.py makemigration <app>` goes correctly 
`python manage.py migrate` - call errors like above

Only one file from Error List is editable and it is manage.py but I haven't edited it since beggining of project.

So if in my own code I haven't got String variable but Python want to tell me that it can't convert value, does anybody know what can I do or where should I remove this variable?

Comment: What did you change in your models? That is, what migrations are being run? I'm thinking maybe this could happen if you changed a field type.

Comment: @Zevgon done and pasted. But it is like I told before - classes from models haven't got this String variable

Comment: @Rafal Did you provided any default value , i.e been asked while running `python manage.py makemigrations` ?

Comment: @Rajez Yes because Django requires it and if you didn't provide it, it show errors. So yes

Comment: So maybe due to that. what is the field & value , that you have provided?

Comment: Problem is that it show mi error with variable that I haven't got. Class Product from Models.py doesn't change anything. 

Finally I restore previous commit before I started work with new Model and it work. 

But I'm still curious how it is possible to show error with variable that I haven't got in code.

Comment: Not sure. but my assumption is, a invalid type `string` is provided for `Decimal` type field on `makemigrations`